Reference count mechanism in Swift makes me confused
In Swift, when the Retain value becomes 0, it is deleted from memory.
Therefore, dataTask() in the example below must also stop execution when the foo() function ends.
This is because the job variable is a local variable, not a global variable.
But this code runs fine.
completionHandler is called even if the foo() function terminates.
How is this possible? Am I missing something?
func foo() {
    let job = URLSession.share.dataTask(with: url) { _, _, _ in
        // completionHandler is called, but I don't know why
    }
}


Please show actual code that demonstrates the thing you're asking about, not something that you just made up. For starters, the code you've shown wouldn't compile because you're calling URLSession.share instead of the correct URLSession.shared (note the d). And as @timbretimbre points out, it looks like you've also omitted the code that explains exactly the thing that you're asking about.

The code you posted without job.resume() will not call a completionHandler no matter what (i.e. not even related to memory management, the task will simply not run).
But if we correct your code to:
func foo(url: URL) {
    let job = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { _, _, _ in
        // ...
    }
    job.resume()
}

Then indeed, the task will run even though the function completed, and no apparent reference to the task exists. This is unfortunately not mentioned in most of the pages of their docs, but it is explained on this page:

After you create a task, you start it by calling its resume method. The session then maintains a strong reference to the task until the request finishes or fails; you don’t need to maintain a reference to the task unless it’s useful for your app’s internal bookkeeping.

So in other words, when you call job.resume(), the URLSession.shared will start maintaining the strong reference to the URLSessionDataTask object, and thus task won't get evicted.

Good answer. (Voted)

job is a local variable, but URLSession.shared is a singleton, and you're passing the closure (completionHandler) to this singleton. Therefore even when foo is removed from memory, the URLSession.shared and dataTask object which is holding completionHandler of the dataTask are still in memory. As a result at the end of the dataTask operation the completionHandler is called.

No, it's not the completionHandler that is holding the it, it's the task itself that is held. See the explanation I provided. In general, I think, I am yet to see an apple function where the callback is the one retaining without the parent object. It's a sure way to either a memory leak or a crash.

I don't think I said completionHandler is holding something.  She/He was wondering how come even though why even though job is removed from memory completionHandler is still alive and called in the end, and I mentioned it's because of the singleton object which holds the dataTask and eventually completionHandler closure.  I don't know, maybe my message wasn't clear enough. Hope this clarifies it for him/her.

foo is a function — it's unlikely to be "removed from memory" at any point. Perhaps you meant "even when foo returns" or similar?

Ah, I meant "even if job is removed" (the variable that I started my explanation). The problem of using meaningless names :) But actually I think a function can be removed from memory too. As functions are like closures, and once the type that's holding it is removed from memory.  (Although if we take the given example strictly, it is a global function and is not tied to any type, but I'm assuming the person has shared the shorter version of the real case he's having, and in his real example it's part of a type)
